# Data entry into SQL Server CE database not displaying in dgv during runtime

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE database with a table name records and 22 columns and in my form in vb.net I have 19 textboxes and 3 datetimepickers for each of the respective textboxes and also a bound dgv, which I dragged from the query of my tables.

When I run the program and input data into the textboxes and click save it save with the msg "record saved" as programmed but nothing displays in my dgv

Here's my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

Public Class Form1
    Dim Cmd As SqlCeCommand
    Dim con As SqlCeConnection
    Dim affector As Integer

    Dim ConnectionString As String = ("Data Source=C:\Users\chinedu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GUU SPECIALIST HOSPITAL 2\GUU SPECIALIST HOSPITAL 2\Database1.sdf")

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet.PATIENT_RECORD' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.'
    Dim strconnection As String = ("Data Source=C:\Users\chinedu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GUU SPECIALIST HOSPITAL 2\GUU SPECIALIST HOSPITAL 2\Database1.sdf")

 Try
        con = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection("strconnection")
        Dim sql As SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand("Query", con)
        con.Open()
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            MessageBox.Show("Database has failed to connect. System will now terminate.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End
        Else 
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch
        MsgBox("Connection Established")
    End Try
End Sub

'save button'
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Try
        con = New SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        sCommand = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO RECORD([Patient_name],[Patient_Address],[Patient_Date_Of_Birth],[Patient_Phone Number],[Patient_CardNO],[Blood_Group],[Date_Admitted],[Date_Discharged],[Treatment1],[Treatment2],[Treatment3],[Treatment4],[Treatment5],[Treatment6],[Price_Unit1],[Price_Unit2],[Price_Unit3],[Price_Unit4],[Price_Unit5],[Price_Unit6],[Sub_total],[VAT],[Prev_bal],[Net_Total]) values ('" + Patient_AddressTextBox.Text + "','" + Patient_AddressTextBox.Text + "','" + Patient_Date_Of_BirthDateTimePicker.Value.Date + "','" + Phone_NumberTextBox.Text + "','" + Hospital_NumberTextBox.Text + "','" + Blood_Group_TextBox.Text + "','" + Date_AdmittedDateTimePicker.Value.Date + "','" + Date_DischargedDateTimePicker.Value.Date + "','" + Treatment1TextBox.Text + "','" + Treatment2TextBox.Text + "','" + Treatment3TextBox.Text + "','" + Treatment4TextBox.Text + "','" + Treatment5TextBox.Text + "','" + Treatment6TextBox.Text + "','" + Sub_TotalTextBox.Text + "','" + VATTextBox.Text + "','" + Previous_BalTextBox.Text + "','" + Net_TotalTextBox.Text + "',)", con)
        affector = sCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("New record has been saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
End Sub

 Private Sub BtnRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRecord.Click
    strcon = ("Data Source= C:\Users\chinedu\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GUU SPECIALIST HOSPITAL 2\GUU SPECIALIST HOSPITAL 2\Database1.sdf")
    con = New SqlCeConnection(strcon)
    Dim query As String = " SELECT * from Records"
    Dim adpt As New SqlCeDataAdapter(query, con)
    Dim ds As New Database1DataSet()
    adpt.Fill(ds, "Records")
    RecordsDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `DataBind()` your GridView

In Your `BtnRecord_Click` event should be like this

```
 RecordsDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
 RecordsDataGridView.DataBind() `This is your missing line.
```

Also you can make it to load automatically after a new record is added.
Just add those 2 lines to your `Button4_Click` event